# PL/SQL update procedure not working with Varying IN list in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, in-operator, varying

I created pl/sql procedure where the arguments are given indirectly through a string. But the update is not making changes in the table as it should. The code I am using is :

```
 declare
ih varchar2(2000);
begin
ih:=q'<'EC359996',
'39216',
'39220',
'2070706',
'2070710',
'EC521555',
'EC521554',
'1944616',
'1852821',
'2047568',
'1501401',
'4500027246',
'1893240',
'1960896',
'4000003058',
'2022319',
'2051178',
'2022860',
'2023110',
'2023114',
'1848439',
'1848442'>';


update ccex.customer c
     set c.cust_credit_analyst    = 'ss',
         c.cust_secondary_analyst = 'ss1',
         c.cust_collector         = 'ss2'
   where c.subscriber_id = '1020'
   and --select count(*) from ccex.customer where 
   cust_account_number in (ih);

   commit;
   /*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ih);*/

end;
```

I tried by copying the exact string content and it is updating as it should.

Comment: See [**Varying IN list of values in WHERE clause**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/02/varying-in-list-of-values-in-where-clause/)

Comment: I have marked the string as ih:=q'<'EC359996',
'39216',
'39220'>' which should be same as 'EC359996','39216','39220', I also tried the solution given: "select ih from dual", still it doesnt work.

Comment: That's why it is a varying IN list. You cannot do that. Either specify it in the WHERE clause itself, or do as it is explained int he topic marked as duplicate.

Comment: Why did you remove the `oracle` tag? PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language.

Comment: Your `ih` variable is just a string. Why should SQL parse it as a nested table without being told to? [Using a comma-separated list in an SQL query](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, was not able to find the question in my search.Thank you very much Lalit for the help. Since my format was different from the specified example had little trouble understanding the solution.